# how to disable <select> based on user selection in another <select>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i have two `<select>`, named **category** and **category_sport**

i want `<select name='category_sport'>`  disable ,  if i click `<option>sport</option>` in   `<select name='category'>`   ,   i want  enable `<select name='category_sport'>`

Anyone have an idea how ?

```
function disable()
    {
        document.getElementById("katOl").disabled=true;
    }
function enable()
    {
        document.getElementById("katOl").disabled=false;
    }
```

the script above is used in `<option>` ex:

```
<select name='category'>
  <option value="1" onclick='enable()' >sport</option>

</select>



<select id='katOl' name='category_sport'>
    <option value="1">Football</option>

 </select>
```

but isn't work

Comment: Where is the `kat01` id in your HTML code???

Comment: after <select name='category'>

Comment: can u try document.getElementById("katOl").setAttribute('disabled', 'true')

Comment: @Alok Swain: Internet Explorer 8 and earlier does not support setAttribute() method. Here is the reference: w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_setattribute.asp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try something like this

javascript

```
function check(val)
{
    if(val == '1'){
        document.getElementById("katOl").disabled=true;
    }else{
        document.getElementById("katOl").disabled=false;
    }
}
```

html

```
<select name='category' onchange="check(this.value)">
        <option value="" >SELECT</option>
        <option value="1" >sport</option>
</select>
```

Comment: this might be a bit risky with values "1" or not. Either name them correctly or use a name attribute which you can check. Or better, omit the value attribute altogether, the value of the contained textnode is then considered (which would be "sport" in your case).

Answer (score 0):

assuming that your  looks like this :

```
<select name='category_sport' id="katOl"> ... </select>
```

HTML:

```
<select id="myselect" name='category' onchange="changeSelect()">
  <option value="1">sport</option>
</select>
```

Javascript:

```
function changeSelect(){
var mySelect = document.getElementById("myselect");
var selectedValue = e.options[myselect.selectedIndex].value;
if(selectedValue=="1") //sport
 {
   document.getElementById("katOl").disabled=false;
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try like this

```
$("#category").change(function(){
  if($(this).val()=="yourvalue"){
    disable();
  }else{
    enable();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('select[name=category]').change(function(){
    if($(this).val() === '1'){
      $('#katOl').prop('disabled', false);
    } else {
      $('#katOl').prop('disabled', true);
    }
  });
});
```

**[DEMO Link](http://jsbin.com/eRuNoPO/1)**

Answer (score 0):

use onChange event of select tag instead.

```
<select onChange="set_sport_cat(this)">
<option value="1">sport</option>
<option value="2">whatever</option>
</select>

function set_sport_cat(my){
    alert("test");
    if(my.options[0].selected){
        alert("1");
    }else{
        alert("2");
    }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3A6X4/

Answer (score 0):

HTML CODE:

```
<select name='category' id="category">
  <option value="1">sport</option>
  <option value="2">education</option>
</select>
<select id='katOl' name='category_sport'>
  <option value="1">Football</option>
</select>
```

js Code:

```
(function(){
    var cat = document.getElementById('category'),
        katOl = document.getElementById('katOl');
    cat.onchange = function() {
      var v = cat.value;
      if(v === '1') {
          katOl.setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled');
      } else {
          katOl.removeAttribute('disabled');
      }
    }
})();
```

Comment: Internet Explorer 8 and earlier does not support setAttribute() method. Reference: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_setattribute.asp

Comment: ie8 don't support self defined attribute, the disabled attribute is genetically support!

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution:

HTML:

```
<select name="category" onchange="alterSelection(event)">
    <option value="">----</option>
    <option value="1">Sport</option>
    <option value="2">Food</option>
</select>

<select id="katOl" name="category_sport" disabled="disabled">
    <option value="1">Football</option>
    <option value="2">Cricket</option>
</select>
```

JS:

```
function alterSelection(e){
    if( e.target.selectedIndex==1 ){
        document.getElementById("katOl").disabled=false;
    }else{
        document.getElementById("katOl").disabled=true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A much simpler and fun approach:

***[LIVE DEMO](http://jsbin.com/EPEDufi/5/edit)***

```
<select name='category'>
  <option>Sport</option>
  <option>Food</option>
  <option>Travel</option>
</select>

<select name='category_sport'>
  <option>Football</option>
</select>

<select name='category_food' disabled>
  <option>Pizza</option>
</select>

<select name='category_travel' disabled>
  <option>Croatia</option>
</select>
```

jQuery:

```
$('select[name=category] option').click(function(){
  var val = this.value.toLowerCase(); // "Sport" >> "sport"
  $('select[name^=category_]').prop('disabled', 1); // Disable all
  $('select[name=category_'+ val +']').prop('disabled', 0); // Enable
});
```